# WPF Datagrid не связывает вложенное свойство

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Насколько я понимаю, WPF должен связывать с вложенным свойством через точку, но тем не менее,у меня в DataGrid отображается пустое поле:
[image: пустое поле "Имя"]
Ниже дан  XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="storageGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="351" Width="643">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Product.Name}" Width="100" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="100" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Я использую классы, сгенерированные Entity Framework 6, подход Database First. Ниже определение Storage:

```
public partial class Storage
{
    public Nullable<int> ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RoomId { get; set; }
    public int EntryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
}
```

Вот как я беру Storage из базы:

```
 public void InitializeData()
    {
        storageGrid.Items.Clear();

        var dbStorages = Repository.Storages();
        foreach (var storage in dbStorages)
        {
            Storages.Add(storage);
        }
        storageGrid.ItemsSource = Storages;
        storageGrid.Items.Refresh();

    }
```

Как заставить WPF правильно отображать поле Product.Name?

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы были с ленивой загрузкой, но когда я ее отключал, авторизация улетала, поэтому я изменил Repository.Storages() следующим образом:

```
return ctx.Storages.Include(s => s.Product).ToList();
```

Ну и в юзингах добавил

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Чтобы получить extension метода Include  с лямбдочкой ^^